# Increased training time during gridsearch for Support Vector Regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, cross-validation, svm, scikit-learn

I have a set of 5000 samples with 24 features, and I'm runing a Gridsearch using scikit-learn to find optimal values for C, epsilon and gamma in SVR. In total I'm testing 90 different hyperparameter configurations with 5 fold cross validation. Also I included verbose = 10 to get feedback on whats happening. For the first 50 or so hyperparameter configurations the total training time was a couple of seconds and the scores were pretty bad. For the next phew combinations training time scalated to 10 minutes or so and the scores got better. Now evaluating model 64/90 total training time is taking around 200 mins. I've already set n_jobs = -1, and pre_dispatch = '1*n_jobs' and checked in task manager that I didn't have any memory problems. I believe the problem comes when taining with higher values of C (C = 100).

A similar thing happened when evaluating a gaussian procces regressor on the same data set. This time considering only two different kernels in a gridsearch, the worst performing kernel took under a minute to train and the better kernel took around 2 hours.

What is producing this behaviour and can I do something about it? Should I just reduce the number of hyperparameter configurations? Also, are this times reasonable for a 5000 samples data set?